# What is the motivation for supposing a pendulum exhibits circular motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion

The question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/245223/) explains how a pendulum can move in circular motion. I am aware that the central tenet of circular motion is that there is a centripetal force acting radially inward that takes on the form $$F = \frac{mv^2}{r}$$ and that the velocity along this path is tangential to the object's path. The central force is the form taken on by the forces giving rise to circular motion. Thus, I see that if we state that a pendulum does exhibit circular motion, we can use Newton's second law to write force equations where the combination of tension and gravitational force collectively give rise to circular motion. However, I am unsure why it is valid to make the proposition that the pendulum does, in fact, exhibit circular motion. Is this motivated by physical observation?

Comment: Yes. It's easy to make an object dangling from a string  move in a circle. Just let it hang and move your hand a circle for a few seconds, and then hold your hand still.

Comment: It's an obvious constraint. What else should it do? Free itself from the string and walk to the beach? However the model for dealing with the constraint (introducing the inward force) is a bit strange, but it works.

Comment: how does the constraint of a string imply that the path taken should follow a circle? I see that the end of the string limits how far the ball can go, but why should it travel smoothly along the length of the string? sorry if it should be, but this is not very "obvious" to me. @secr

Comment: What do you mean? The case where you consider the kinematics of the string (how it bends etc.)? Like in this paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327655249_Swinging_beam_of_beads_transforming_into_a_simple_pendulum_of_the_same_length ?

Comment: I never knew the word was actually tenet. That is embarrassing. Thank you for clarifying. @PM2Ring

Answer (score 3):

> I am aware that the central tenant of circular motion is that there is a centripetal force acting radially inward that takes on the form $$F = \frac{mv^2}{r}$$ and that the velocity along this path is tangential to the object's path.

This is only true for **uniform** circular motion. For general circular motion it is neither necessary for the magnitude of the force to have that value nor is it necessary for the net force to be radially inward.

The only requirement for general circular motion is that the distance from the center must be constant. Since the distance is determined by the length of the rod and the rod is inextensible, this condition is met.

Comment: It would be better to look at the physical implementation of the circular motion constraint due to a massless fixed-length rod rather than a string. A rigid rod always ensures the circular motion constraint, while a string corresponds to a unilateral constraint (see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86723/). An inextensible string can still be bent and folded.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 thanks for the suggestion. I agree and updated the answer accordingly

Comment: I get the rod case, but I think I don't see why the string case is equivalent to the rod case. I think it might just be an implicit assumption that comes with the use of a strong that I was not aware of? And then this model works well to explain things, so we use it?

Comment: @Relativisticcucumber the distance $d$ between the ends of an ideal rod of length $L$ is $d=L$. The distance between the ends of an ideal string is $d\le L$ with $d=L$ only in the case that the string is under tension.

Comment: Could you explain why the idea of considering a massless string under tension as a rigid rod is valid? Is there a nonobservational way to see this? @Dale

Comment: @Relativisticcucumber have you never played with a string? If you fix one end and move the other then you can move it freely until it gets a certain distance from the fixed end.  At that point it suddenly gets tension, you can go no further away, and you can draw a circle if you keep it under tension. Ideal strings capture that same behavior

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it is in the first moment just an assumption. It is assumed, that the physical problem we want to describe is a circular motion around the fixed position of the pendulum with a given, constant radius. With this boundary condition, the problem can be solved the way you described it.

The fact, that this boundary condition is a good idea could theoretically be proven, by solving the whole problem, including a variable rope length, or even shape, including the density of the rope, and so on. One would see, that in usual settings the motion would be very close to circular.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In practice, the movement is not always circular. It depends on the initial conditions. Even keeping the string with $r=R$, with zero initial velocity, if the initial angle is greater than $\pi/2$ the movement will clearly not be circular at first.

The problem comes from over-modeling the rope. Its behavior changes radically depending on the value of the radius. We are therefore obliged to make a hypothesis (for exemple, $r=R$ and $T>0$ towards the inside), to solve the equations and to check that it is coherent. Most often, it is implicitly assumed that the solution is unique.